# Windows BitTorrent client, with directory per download

Tags: windows, gratis, desktop-client, bittorrent

I have been using Utorrent for my (legal only) downloads.

It has an option "move completed downloads to ... <directory>".

How the program interprets that is "when any download completes, move it to the current value of <directory>".

How I want my bittorrent client to interpret it is "when any download completes, move it to the value of <directory> when the download began".

example:

- set directory to A
- start download 1
- set directory to B
- start download 2
- both downloads complete

Utorrent puts them both in B; I want 1 in A and 2 in B. Please let me know if that is not clear.

Other features are a bonus - the more, the better. Something long established and well supported is better, but that omen feature is of prime importance.

Comment: When adding a torrent via Tixati you can do this.

Comment: Then why not post that as an answer?

Comment: I am currently examining https://www.techradar.com/reviews/qbittorrent which is the most popular client & seems to do what I want, but I will need to do some more tests before I can be certain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://qbittorrent.org does exactly what I want. Plus, it is one of the most pouplar torrent clients and "qBittorrent runs and provides the same features on all major platforms (Linux, macOS, Windows, OS/2, FreeBSD)".